# Getting redirect error even after CORS enabled

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect

I'm trying to switch control to another route (NOT **next** route) having path **/getProfile** when the condition is not matched. For this, I'm using `res.redirect()`

(**Query 1:** Is it the right way to passing control from one router to another? If no, how would I do it?)

Here's some code from my server side JS:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    next();
});

app.use('/getProfile', function (req, res, next) {
  var userName = req.session.userName;
  if(userName && userName != 'undefined'){
        console.log("if");
      next('route');
  } else {
    console.log("else");
    res.redirect("getProfile");
    next('route');
  }
});

app.post('/getProfile', function (req, res, next) {
    //do something
});
```

Client side code:

```
$scope.getProfile = function(){
loggedInUser=$("input[name='email']").val();
 $http({
    method : "POST",
    url : "http://192.168.43.200:3000/getProfile",
    data: JSON.stringify({userName: loggedInUser}),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
}).then(function mySuccess(response) {
    //do something
}, function myError(response) {
    //do something
});
}
```

But I'm getting following error when I hit request to /getProfile from browser:

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.43.200:3000/getProfile. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)**

**Query 2:** Am I doing something wrong?

**Query 3:** Is there any difference between passing (I don't know what it is called, I've already asked about it in Query 1) control to another route and redirect?

NOTE: I'm getting above error only after introducing `app.use("*")` and **redirect** part.

Please answer these queries. I'm really confused.

Comment: `Response for preflight` - do you understand this part of the message?

Comment: No sir. What is it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

Comment: it means your request is preflighted with an `OPTIONS` request, and clearly you are not handling it as is *required* by `CORS`

Comment: But it is a `POST` request? what is `OPTIONS`?